# iOS Cursor head truncated when selecting text

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

When selecting text in UITextField or UITextView, a cursor that pops out to help with selecting the text. The cursor's top head is cut by the border of the UITextView. Is this an issue that I can fix or its Apple's issue?

Comment: Increase the height of your test field

Comment: The image is from a text view and the height is tall but the issue still persists

Comment: Just for testing purpose could you increase the height by 50 and try. Print the intrinsic content size of the text view and then print the actual size of the text view